# TCP detect disconnected server from client

Tags: java, tcp, stream

I'm writing a simple TCP client/server program pair in Java, and the server must disconnect if the client hasn't sent anything in 10 seconds.  socket.setSoTimeout() gets me that, and the server disconnects just fine. The problem is - how can I get the client to determine if the server is closed? Currently I'm using DataOutputStream for writing to the server, and some answers here on SO suggest that writing to a closed socket will throw an IOException, but that doesn't happen.

What kind of writer object should I use to send arbitrary byte blocks to the server, that would throw an exception or otherwise indicate that the connection has been closed remotely?

Edit: here's the client code. This is a test function that reads one file from the file system and sends it to the server. It sends it in chunks, and pauses for some time between each chunk.

```
public static void sendFileWithTimeout(String file, String address, int dataPacketSize, int timeout) {
    Socket connectionToServer = null;
    DataOutputStream outStream = null;
    FileInputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        connectionToServer = new Socket(address, 2233);

        outStream = new DataOutputStream(connectionToServer.getOutputStream());

        Path fileObject = Paths.get(file);

        outStream.writeUTF(fileObject.getFileName().toString());

        byte[] data = new byte[dataPacketSize];

        inStream = new FileInputStream(fileObject.toFile());
        boolean fileFinished = false;
        while (!fileFinished) {
            int bytesRead = inStream.read(data);
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                fileFinished = true;
            } else {
                outStream.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " wrote " + bytesRead + " bytes.");
                Thread.sleep(timeout);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Something something.");
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem sending data to server.", e);
    } finally {
        TCPUtil.silentCloseObject(inStream);
        TCPUtil.silentCloseObject(outStream);
        TCPUtil.silentCloseObject(connectionToServer);
    }
}
```

I'd expect the outStream.write to throw an IOException when it tries to write to a closed server, but nothing.

Comment: _"but that doesn't happen"_. Then what happend when server was closed?

Comment: Your client input stream will indicate that the stream is closed when the server closes the socket. And if you happen to be writing to outputstream while the server at the same time closes the socket, you should also get an exception. Not sure why you are not getting exception. Can you show some code?

Comment: @CHOCKO - next to nothing. The client wrote the data to the stream and exited normally, without caring that the server is no longer there to read the data.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd expect the outStream.write to throw an IOException when it tries to write to a closed server, but nothing.

It won't do that the first time, because of the socket send buffer. If you keep writing, it will eventually throw an IOException: 'connection reset'. If you don't have data to get to that point, you will never find out that the peer has closed.

Comment: Does that apply to all methods of writing? Or would it be solved by using something other than DataOutputStream?

Comment: @user1638190 (a) yes (b) no.

Answer (score -1):

Remember `ServerSocket.setSoTimeout()` is different from client's function with same name.

For server, this function only throws `SocketTimeoutException` for you to catch it if timeout is expired, but the server socket still remains.

For client, `setSoTimeout()` relates to 'read timeout' for stream reading.

In your case, you must show your server code of **closing the connected socket** after catching `SocketTimeoutException` => ensure server closed the associated socket with a specified client. **If done, at client side**, your code line:

`throw new RuntimeException("Problem sending data to server.", e);`

will be called.

**[Update]**

I noticed that you stated to set timeout for the accepted socket at server side to **10 secs** (=10,000 milliseconds); for that period, did your client complete all the file sending? if it did, never the exception occurs.

**[Suggest]**

for probing, just comment out your code of reading file content to send to server, and try replacing with several lines of writing to output stream:

```
outStream.writeUTF("ONE");
outStream.writeUTF("TWO");
outStream.writeUTF("TREE");
```

Then you can come to the conclusion.

Comment: The ServerSocket isn't closed - it remains open to work with other potential clients. The server's Socket object (the one receiving data from this specific client) is the one that has a timeout set and gets closed if no data is received.

Comment: The socket I mentioned when server accepted a client connection is `client socket` (it is equivalent to client's socket but has revert read/write direction). How you know that it's closed properly on your server side?

Comment: This is just more confusion. Setting a timeout on a `ServerSocket` causes `accept()` to throw a `SocketTimeoutException` if the timeout expires. Setting a timeout on a `Socket` causes the read methods to throw `SocketTimeoutException` if the timeout expires. There is no such code thing as `read_timeout` so I don't know why it is formatted as code. He's already stated that 'the server disconnects just fine'. The client won't necessarily detect the server close at all: see my answer.

Comment: @EJP: I misused the shortcut to embed this link for 'read timout': http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

Comment: @KelvinTrinh The OP didn't say anything about calling `ServerSocket.setSoTimeout().` `Socket.setSoTImeout()` on the other hand can be caled at either the server or the client, with the same effect in both cases: it sets a read timeout; and that is what the OP states he has done. The client doesn't need to complete sending the entire file within ten seconds: the read timeout restarts every time you call `read()`. There's nothing in your link that contradicts anything I've said here.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to **flush** and **close** your stream after written like outStream.flush(); outStream.close(); inStream.close();

Comment: No. close() implies flush(), and closing either the input or output stream of a Socket closes the other stream and the Socket.